# How can I turn a flat list into a 2D array in python?

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, numpy

How can I turn a list such as:

```
data_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

into a array (I'm using numpy) that looks like:

```
data_array = [ [0,1] , [2,3] , [4,5] , [6,7] , [8,9] ]
```

Can I slice segments off the beginning of the list and append them to an empty array?

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array(data_list).reshape(-1, 2)
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9]])
```

(The [`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy.ndarray.reshape) method returns a new "view" on the array; it doesn't copy the data.)

Comment: Numpy is a big hammer for such a problem

Comment: Numpy is in the OP's requirements.

Answer (score 2):

```
def nest_list(list1,rows, columns):    
        result=[]               
        start = 0
        end = columns
        for i in range(rows): 
            result.append(list1[start:end])
            start +=columns
            end += columns
        return result
```

for:

```
 list1=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
nest_list(list1,4,4)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
```