# Turning a list into nested lists in python

Tags: python, list, nested

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How can I turn a list into an array in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614261/how-can-i-turn-a-list-into-an-array-in-python)

How can I turn a list such as:

```
data_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

into a list of lists such as:

```
new_list = [ [0,1,2] , [3,4,5] , [6,7,8] ]
```

ie I want to group ordered elements in a list and keep them in an ordered list. How can I do this?

Comment: You ask that already less than one hour ago.

Comment: Sorry -  I can't figure out the criterium for defining the subgroups on yur question. In your example, all numbers are "ordered" - so do you want ordered elements AND subgroups of max-lenght 3? Or just lenght 3 for each subgroup?

Comment: @Sentinel: Not strict duplicate, because does not involve `numpy`. But perhaps close enough. Thanks

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of the referenced question at all. The solutions for `list` and `numpy.array` are entirely different.

Comment: @Sentinel: You're correct that it is similar but I needed to use lists and not arrays now. When I used the np.reshape method from the previous question to revert back to a 1D array, I lost all internal grouping -- my data was not simply [1,2,3...] but a lot of 3-tuples. I needed a way to put back the organization into threes not using arrays. I think this question is thus useful on its own merit and is significantly different than the previous one.

Comment: @Double AA: Please consider now on the feedback you have received, to more holistically describe what are you aiming for. IMHO, you will have a good starting position if you'll just expand the above comment. Thanks

Comment: What I really have is a 48x365 element numpy array where each element is a list containing 3 integers. I want to be able to turn it into a 1x17520 array with all the lists intact as elements, and be able to turn it back again. The numpy.reshape method seems to break the elements into three separate integers and makes a 1x52560 array. So I either need a new way of rearranging the original array or a way of grouping the elements in the new array (which are still in order) back into lists of 3. Thanks for your help.

Comment: AFAIU, You actually have a `numpy` array with shape (48, 365, 3) and you'll figured out that a view of it as reshaped to shape (17520, 3) will enable you to perform some (shape preserving) calculations straightforward manner. Now the reversing reshaping will be quite natural. Anyway, as I suggested, please ask a new question with detailed descriptions (of your problem). These comments may be a good starting point for such descriptions, but only a starting point. Thanks

Comment: @eat Wow! Excellent point! I don't know why I didn't see that before. That solves the issue with np.reshape and now I can use that. No need for another thread. Thanks again!

Comment: But for the `SO` community it still may be relevant to post a question including relevant part of our discussion. You actually may to post the answer you find by yourself (but let other ones first digest it decent long time). So, please, I'm encouraging you to write a clear new question about this, so all of us can benefit of it. Please note that these comments will remain in the shadows for majority of `SO` community. Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This assumes that data_list has a length that is a multiple of three

```
i=0
new_list=[]
while i<len(data_list):
  new_list.append(data_list[i:i+3])
  i+=3
```

Answer (score 90):

This groups each 3 elements in the order they appear:

```
new_list = [data_list[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(data_list), 3)]
```

Give us a better example if it is not what you want.

Comment: I ran into a similar situation to the above question and your code worked perfect! I've been struggling at the last stage. So glad that I could address this.

Answer (score 8):

Something like:

```
map (lambda x: data_list[3*x:(x+1)*3], range (3))
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on [the answer from Fred Foo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6614280/1033581), if you're already using `numpy`, you may use [`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy.ndarray.reshape) to get a 2d array without copying the data:

```
import numpy
new_list = numpy.array(data_list).reshape(-1, 3)
```

Comment: I like this, but it only works when the array has a number of elements that's a multiple of 3, otherwise it will throw a ValueError.

Answer (score 4):

`new_list = [data_list[x:x+3] for x in range(0, len(data_list) - 2, 3)]`

List comprehensions for the win :)

Answer (score 1):

The following function expands the original context to include any desired list of lists structure:

```py
def gen_list_of_lists(original_list, new_structure):
    assert len(original_list) == sum(new_structure), \
    "The number of elements in the original list and desired structure don't match"
        
    list_of_lists = [[original_list[i + sum(new_structure[:j])] for i in range(new_structure[j])] \
                     for j in range(len(new_structure))]
        
    return list_of_lists
```

Using the above:

```py
data_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    
new_list = gen_list_of_lists(original_list=data_list, new_structure=[3,3,3])
# The original desired outcome of [[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8]]

new_list = gen_list_of_lists(original_list=data_list, new_structure=[2,3,3,1])
# [[0, 1], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The below one is more optimized and quite straightforward.

```
data_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
result =[]
i=0
while i <(len(data_list)-2):
    result.append(data_list[i:i+3])
    i+=3
print(result)

**output**
```

[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]

Comment: I fixed the code. lots of errors. However, I am not sure if this solves the problem. downvoting the answer.

Comment: @JoeFerndz can i know what you have fixed in this ? have you run the code?

Comment: Because I remember writing the working code. What changes have you done?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generalized solution

```
import math

data_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
batch_size=3

n_batches=math.ceil(len(data_list)/batch_size)

[data_list[x*batch_size:min(x*batch_size+batch_size,len(data_list))] 
    for x in range(n_batches)]
```

It works even if the last sublist is not the same size as the rest (<batch_size)

Answer (score -1):

Do you have any sort of selection criteria from your original list?

Python does allow you to do this:

```
new_list = []
new_list.append(data_list[:3])
new_list.append(data_list[3:6])
new_list.append(data_list[6:])

print new_list
# Output:  [ [0,1,2] , [3,4,5] , [6,7,8] ]
```

Comment: FWIW, this won't be very practical one, when you try to generalize the pattern OP described. Thanks

Comment: Oh I didn't know if the OP was wondering if embedded lists were possible in Python or if there was a way to convert a list into one.