# python matrix creation without using numpy or anything and max sum of rows and columns

Tags: python, matrix

Want to create a matrix like below in python

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

but not sure how to do, i tried list comprehension like below

```
[[y+x for y in range(4)] for x in range(4)]
```

which gives output like below

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

and also want print the row with maximum sum and columns with maximum sum.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614891/turning-a-list-into-nested-lists-in-python

Answer (score 4):

```
[[x * 4 + y + 1 for y in range(4)] for x in range(4)]
```

which is equivalent to:

```
[[(x << 2) + y for y in range(1, 5)] for x in range(4)]
```

Here's a little benchmark:

```
import timeit


def f1():
    return [[x * 4 + y + 1 for y in range(4)] for x in range(4)]


def f2():
    return [[(x << 2) + y for y in range(1, 5)] for x in range(4)]


def f3():
    a = range(1, 5)
    return [[(x << 2) + y for y in a] for x in range(4)]

N = 5000000
print timeit.timeit('f1()', setup='from __main__ import f1', number=N)
print timeit.timeit('f2()', setup='from __main__ import f2', number=N)
print timeit.timeit('f3()', setup='from __main__ import f3', number=N)

# 13.683984791
# 13.4605276559
# 9.65608339037
# [Finished in 36.9s]
```

Where we can conclude both f1 & f2 methods give almost the same performance. So it'd be a good choice to calculate the inner `range(1,5)` only once like f3

Answer (score 3):

The range function accepts 3 arguments `start`, `end` and `step`. You can use one range with step 4 and another one for creating the nested lists using the outer range.

```
>>> [[i for i in range(i, i+4)] for i in range(1, 17, 4)]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

here is another way with one `range`:

```
>>> main_range = range(1, 5)
>>> [[i*j + (i-1)*(4-j) for j in main_range] for i in main_range]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

And here is a Numpythonic approach:

```
>>> n = 4
>>> np.split(np.arange(1, n*n + 1), np.arange(n ,n*n, n))
[array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6, 7, 8]), array([ 9, 10, 11, 12]), array([13, 14, 15, 16])]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
In [1]: [range(1,17)[n:n+4] for n in range(0, len(range(1,17)), 4)]
Out[1]: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a quick fix

```
[([x-3,x-2,x-1,x]) for x in range(1,17) if x%4 ==0]
```

But what do you mean by maximum sum of column and row

Comment: for ex. in all rows which of the row has the maximum sum, for ex. 2nd row liks this [1 2 3] has maximum sum of = some value, here its 6.