# Methods to search and replace values in nested lists

Tags: python

I'd like to search and replace values in a list of of list. I've cobbled together answers to:

1. [Flatten a nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/2694260)
2. [Search for and replace a value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1540069/2694260)
3. [Regroup the flat list into a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6615011/2694260)

My current code works however I feel that it's more convoluted then it needs to be. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

```
# Create test data- a list of lists which each contain 2 items
numbers = list(range(10))
list_of_lists = [numbers[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(numbers), 2)]

# Flatten the list of lists
flat_list = [item for sublist in list_of_lists for item in sublist]
# Search for and replace values
modified_list = [-1 if e > 5 else e for e in flat_list]
# Regroup into a list of lists
regrouped_list_of_lists = [modified_list[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(modified_list), 2)]
```

Comment: This is probably the most Pythonic way of doing it. If it works and is readable, don't fix it!

Comment: @TheLazyScripter *If it works and is readable, don't fix it* Nah, not in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the replacements in the sublists in a *nested list comprehension* without having to flatten and regroup:

```
numbers = list(range(10))
list_of_lists = [numbers[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(numbers), 2)]
# here
list_of_lists = [[-1 if e > 5 else e for e in sublist] for sublist in list_of_lists]
```

Answer (score 2):

You're already using list comprehensions, just combine them:

```
replaced_list_of_lists = [
            [-1 if e > 5 else e for e in inner_list]
                for inner_list in list_of_lists
        ]
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good answer. List comprehension add already much to the readability, and combining them doesn't help much.

Comment: Well this definitely removes some of the code so why not, but I personally try to avoid heavy use of list comprehension.

Comment: @AntoineBolvy however, the original solution of flatting / replacing / recombing only works if you know exactly the format of the original list.  If you want a general solution, you need either list comprehensions or nested for loops.

Comment: Yeah of course, although it is useful to not forget that nested list comprehensions *are* nested for loops ;)