# Reorder list in Python

Tags: python, reshape

I would like to reorder a python list:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...]
```

to the following form:

```
[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],...]
```

What is the fastest way to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614891/turning-a-list-into-nested-lists-in-python

Comment: What happens at the end of your source list? Do you just get a two-element list and a one-element list in your result?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the link given.

Comment: Really easy to do in one line :

    a = [1,2,3,4,5] and then
    b = [[a[i], a[i+1], a[i+2]] for i in range (0, len(a) -2)]

Comment: `b = [a[i:i+3] for i in range(len(a))]` Does depend on Ulrich Schwarz's question though.

Comment: b = [a[i:i+3] for i in range (0, len(a)-2)] will do too.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.
Initial question want to produce [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)].
This question want to produce [(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(3,4,5),...,(6,7,8),(7,8,9)].

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> new_list = []
>>> for index in range(len(a)-2):
    new_list.append(a[index:index+3])


>>> new_list
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: or try zip(a, a[1:], a[2:])