# Python iterating a list and creating a nested list out of all iterations

Tags: python

I've been trying to figure out how I could code the following:

I have a list say:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I am trying to multiply each element in groups of 2 and so I'm expecting 4 lists at the end:

```
[-1, -2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, -2, -3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, -3, -4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, -4, -5]
```

Now with these 4 lists I intend to create a nested list again say:

```
M = [[-1, -2, 3, 4, 5], [1, -2, -3, 4, 5],[1, 2, -3, -4, 5], [1, 2, 3, -4, -5]]
```

So far I got this:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
L2 = L.copy()
print(L)

for x in range(0,2):
    for y in range(x,2+x):
        N = []
        L2[y] = L2[y] * -1
        N.append(L2)
        print(N)
```

and it's showing as this

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[[-1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
[[-1, -2, 3, 4, 5]]
[[-1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
[[-1, 2, -3, 4, 5]]
```

I can't generate the nested list because I don't know how to call a list whose elements have been modified from the loop I created. I am also having issues with my loop. I want it to read the old list in a fresh slate rather than referring to the altered list from the previous loop.

I'm very new to python but I am enjoying learning this new language. Often times I get stuck and easily figure out what I need to happen. This one is a bit trickier on my end so I am asking for help. Thanks!

Comment: I believe you can find the answer in this question. Just insert the answer from the thread into your codes with slight modification  [Turning a list into nested lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614891/turning-a-list-into-nested-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
L2 = []
print(L)

k = 2   #the number of items to be modified
for x in range(0, len(L)-k+1):
    N = L.copy()
    for y in range(x, x+k):
        N[y] *= -1
    L2.append(N)
    print(N)
```

You can change the k value if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Cool question. try this:

L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

```
def foo(lst, inx):
    print(inx)
    new_l = lst.copy()
    new_l[inx] *= -1
    new_l[inx+1] *= -1
    return new_l

[foo(L, i) for i in range(4)]
```

The output is:

```
[[-1, -2, 3, 4, 5], [1, -2, -3, 4, 5], [1, 2, -3, -4, 5], [1, 2, 3, -4, -5]]
```