# How to covert a list into a list with sublists? python

Tags: python

I'm making a little data base on python.

```
my_list = ['jack', 'liam', 'gary', 'poly']
```

I want to convert the list into this

```
result = [('jack', 'liam'),('liam', 'gary'),('gary', 'poly')]
```

Is there anyway i can do this?

Comment: See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487049/python-list-of-lists, seems quite relevant.

Comment: Or perhaps this post could help too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614891/turning-a-list-into-nested-lists-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zip` will return a tuple from two iterables; if you take the same list, but shifted as you wish (in this case, one element forward) you can have your expected result.

Also, the generator will exhaust on the shortest iterable (the second one).

```py
>>> [(a,b) for (a,b) in zip(my_list, my_list[1:])]
[('jack', 'liam'), ('liam', 'gary'), ('gary', 'poly')]
```

Comment: can you explain zip here, so i can add a comment to my code to remember.

Comment: You can check my answer and also the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: `list(zip(my_list, my_list[1:]))` will work the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use `list comprehension`

- Iterate till second last value of the list
- get current and next value as a tuple.

```
my_list = ['jack', 'liam', 'gary', 'poly']
new_list = [(my_list[i],my_list[i+1]) for i in range(len(my_list)-1)]

print(new_list)
>> [('jack', 'liam'), ('liam', 'gary'), ('gary', 'poly')]
```

Or Use `zip()`

which will return consecutive combinations as tuple.

```
my_list = ['jack', 'liam', 'gary', 'poly']
new_list = list(zip(my_list, my_list[1:]))

print(new_list)
>> [('jack', 'liam'), ('liam', 'gary'), ('gary', 'poly')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ['jack', 'liam', 'gary', 'poly']

result_list = [(my_list[i],my_list[i+1]) for i in range(len(my_list) - 1)]

print(result_list)
```

Output

```
[('jack', 'liam'), ('liam', 'gary'), ('gary', 'poly')]
```

We can fetch 2 elements into a tuple till we iterate and reach the second last element.

Answer (score 0):

```py
result = []
my_list = ['jack', 'liam', 'gary', 'poly']
for i, item in enumerate(my_list):
   if i+1 == len(my_list): break
   result.append((item, my_list[i+1]))
```

Or more Pythonic and elegant way:

```py
result = [(item, my_list[i+1]) for i, item in enumerate(my_list) if i+1 < len(my_list)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ['jack', 'liam', 'gary', 'poly']
result = []
for i in range(0, len(my_list)):
    if not i > len(my_list)-2:
        result.append((my_list[i], my_list[i+1]))
```

output

```
[('jack', 'liam'), ('liam', 'gary'), ('gary', 'poly')]
```